# Hide and Unhide text using popper.js

Tags: popper.js

I have the following popper.js script and I want that when I click a button a text appears and when I click the button again the text disappears. The script shown only unhide the text.

```
        var ref = $('#button-a');        
    var popup = $('#popup');
    popup.hide();

    ref.click(function(){
            popup.show(); 
            var popper = new Popper(ref,popup,{
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    onCreate: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                    },
                    modifiers: {
                            flip: {
                                    behavior: ['bottom']
                            },
                            offset: { 
                                    enabled: true,
                                    offset: '0,10'
                            }
                    }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handler is never calling .hide() (I assume these are the JQuery show and hide functions?). You either need to use .toggle() instead of .show() or set up a conditional that handles the case where the popup is already visible and calls .hide().